Objeto Frame oculta el evento click de los botones que estan en él
Tengo en VBA un form con botones creados en tiempo de ejecución y funciona bien, logro capturar e identificar el evento click de todos los botones. La situación es que cuando adiciono un frame (por diseño) para contener los botones el evento click de los botones se torna indetectable.

fijate como enganchas los eventos, si los botones pasaron a ser childs del frame/panel tal vez tengas que ajustar. un poco de code estaría bien para ver

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
